# Delete confirmation rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a delete option on a scheduled message, I simply want a quick popup verification that user wanted to delete(Are You Sure?). What's the simplest way to accomplish this?

Here is a screenshot and some code.

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Listing Scheduled Messages</h2>
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><%= sortable 'body', 'Messages' %></th>
    <th><%= sortable 'send_at', 'Sent Time' %></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @message.each do |message| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= message.body %></td>
      <td>Send out in: <%= time_ago_in_words message.send_at %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_message_path(message) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Delete', message_path(message),method: :delete, :confirm=>'Are you sure?' %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <p><%= link_to "Send Message", root_path %></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is not working? when you click Delete do you not get a confirmation?

Comment: Are you try this ? `data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use **Rails 4**, the [syntax has changed](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), so `confirm` attribute is now handled in the `data` hash.

**Before:**  `confirm: "Are you sure?"`

**After:**  `data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }`

Try this:

`<%= link_to 'Delete', message_path(message),method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?' }%>`